# Writing files after fread with a new name

Tags: r, data.table, lapply, fread

Assuming that I have files like this,

```
cat("TRIAL\nTRIAL\nblah\nVARIABLE,X1,X2\nA,1,2\n", file="myfile1.csv")
cat("blah\nVARIABLE\nTRIAL,A1,A2\nA,1,2\n", file="myfile2.csv")
cat("blah\nblah\nVARIABLE\nTRIAL,Z1,Z2\nA,1,2\n", file="myfile3.csv")

flist<-list.files(pattern = "myfile.*.csv")

[1] "myfile1.csv" "myfile2.csv" "myfile3.csv"
```

and I read these files with `fread` and `!grep` some strings "TRIAL"

```
result <- lapply(flist,function(x)fread(paste("grep -v TRIAL",x),header = FALSE)[,FNAME:=x])
```

then if I try to write these files like this `"myfile1_new.csv" "myfile2_new.csv" "myfile3_new.csv" ;`

```
lapply(result,function(x) write.table(x,file = gsub("(.*)(\\..*)", "\\1_new\\2", flist),row.names = FALSE,col.names = TRUE))
```

> Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :    invalid
>   'description' argument In addition: Warning message: In if (file ==
>   "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :   the condition
>   has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

I know `result` is a list

`str(result)` List of 3, but I'm getting error like above.

In addition how can I combine `fread` and `write.table` inside of same `lapply` loop?

regards

Comment: What is the content `result` ? It may be a list but is it a list of the objects you expect (i.e. writable) ?

Comment: @steveb please reproduce the example. You will see inside of the result.

Comment: gsub("(.*)(\\..*)", "\\1_new\\2", flist) is a vector of length 3 when write.table is expecting a single character vector...maybe lapply(1:length(result), function(n) write.table(result[[n]], file = gsub("(.*)(\\..*)", "\\1_new\\2", flist)[n],row.names = FALSE,col.names = TRUE))

Comment: @chinsoon12 Don't you want `flist` to also be indexed with `n` (i.e. `flist[n]`) ?

Comment: @Alexander I had missed something in your post, I was able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @steveb, i used it outside of  gsub("(.*)(\\..*)", "\\1_new\\2", flist)[n]. i think its a minor typo error which Alexander will quickly catch on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First part:

`gsub("(.*)(\\..*)", "\\1_new\\2", flist)` returns a list, so you need to pass an element of it into `write.table`, I would do it by using `seq_along()` inside the `lapply()` function as following:

```
cat("TRIAL\nTRIAL\nblah\nVARIABLE,X1,X2\nA,1,2\n", file = "myfile1.csv")
cat("blah\nVARIABLE\nTRIAL,A1,A2\nA,1,2\n", file = "myfile2.csv")
cat("blah\nblah\nVARIABLE\nTRIAL,Z1,Z2\nA,1,2\n", file = "myfile3.csv")

flist <- list.files(pattern = "myfile.*.csv")

result <-
  lapply(flist, function(x)
    fread(x, header = FALSE)[, FNAME := x])

# str(gsub("(.*)(\\..*)", "\\1_new\\2", flist))  # returns a list

lapply(seq_along(result), function(i) {
  # print(gsub("(.*)(\\..*)", "\\1_new\\2", flist))  # a list
  # print(gsub("(.*)(\\..*)", "\\1_new\\2", flist)[i])  # this is what you want
  write.table(
    result[i],
    file = gsub("(.*)(\\..*)", "\\1_new\\2", flist[i]),
    row.names = FALSE,
    col.names = TRUE
  )
})
```

Second part (merging into one `lapply()`) would probably involve a pipe (`%>%`) operator from `dplyr` package.

#### Edit: Second part:

```
library(dplyr)

lapply(
  seq_along(flist),
  FUN = function(i) {
    # fread(paste("grep -v TRIAL", x), header = FALSE)[, FNAME := x])
    fread(flist[i], header = FALSE)[, FNAME := flist[i]] %>%
      write.table(
        file = gsub("(.*)(\\..*)", "\\1_new\\2", flist[i]),
        row.names = FALSE,
        col.names = TRUE
      )
  }
)
```

Or you can just assign the result of `fread()` to a temp variable and then do `write.table(temp, file = ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (filename in flist) {
  d = fread(paste("grep -v TRIAL", filename), header = FALSE)[, FNAME := filename]
  write.table(d, gsub("(.*)(\\..*)", "\\1_new\\2", filename),
              row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
}
```